# Who is responsible for creating part of main class?

Tags: javascript, typescript

There is a major class `Panorama` with parts as composition `PanoramaViewOver`.

```
class Panorama {
  panoramaViewOver: PanoramaViewOver | null;
}
```

Who is responsible to create a class `PanoramaViewOver` if needed?
I can create wrapper class that creates a new `Panorama()` and creates a `PanoramaViewOver()`:

```
class Creator {
  panorama: Panorama;

  createPanorama() {
    this.panorama = new Panorama();
  }

  createPanoramaViewOver() {
    const view  = new PanoramaViewOver();
    if(this.panorama) this.panorama.view = view;
  }
}
```

Another way is create a public method `createPanoramaViewOver()` inside main class `Panorama()`.

What is a better way?

Comment: Please [edit] the code to be a self-contained [mre] that demonstrates your issue when pasted as-is into a standalone IDE without introducing unrelated errors.  Right now I see [a bunch of errors](https://tsplay.dev/wjXOlm), none of which you're asking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `createPanorama()` and `createPanoramaViewOver()` I would use `create()` which *implicitly* creates a `Panorama` instance and `createWithPanorama(Panorama panorama)` which takes an already initialized `Panorama` object.

Both methods would need to be static resembling a [factory method pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).

This way you can set `panorama.view` outside of the `Creator` class.

It would look like this:

```
class Creator {
  private _panorama: Panorama | null;

  constructor(panorama : Panorama | null) {
      this._panorama = panorama;  
  }

  static create() {
    return new Creator(new Panorama());
  }

  static createWithPanorama(panorama : Panorama | null) {
    return new Creator(panorama);
  }
}
```

You would use it like this:

```
let creator = Creator.create();
let creatorWithoutPanorama = Creator.createWithPanorama(null);

let p = new Panorama();
p.view = /* something */;

let creatorWithPanoramaViewOver = Creator.createWithPanorama(p);
```

---

It's not idiomatic to initialize *each* member of a class with *different* methods.

You usually do that in one place *only*, most of the time in the constructor.